# Square UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` in my `viewController`. I'm trying to make it squared corners. Out of all the things I tried, the only option is to have my own image. How can I get my image to be exactly like the standard `segmentedControl`, but just squared corners? Is there a source file that I can tweak? (I have Photoshop.)

Here is what I tried:

- Resized the `SegementedControl` so that its' frame is outside the
  boundaries `superview`.

> This didn't work because the text at the last `segment` is at the very
>   edge, so the `superview` blocked the text.

- Added a `segment` at first and last index, and set their widths to 1.
  (That's the smallest it'll allow me.)

> This didn't look so nice, because the first and last `segments` are
>   still noticeable.

So the only other choice (I think), is to add an image.

Comment: Have you tried setting mySegmentControl.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0?

Comment: Can't you use the first method, but make the font a little smaller so it doesn't get cut off?

Comment: @rdelmar Good point!! Is there a way to make the text align to the right?

Comment: I don't think you can set the alignment, but you can use setContentOffset:forSegmentAtIndex: to offset the text.